# Angular http stream double request [GET,HEAD]

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I am working on learning Angular[6], and while I don't have a very strong understanding of Observables, I feel like I've at least built a usable example. However, I am running into a consistent problem which leads me to believe that I am using a poor approach or have fundamentally misunderstood something.

In my ApiService:

```
 getTransaction(uid:number):Observable<Transaction[]>{
   let url = this.endPoint + '/transaction';
   if(uid !== undefined){
     url += '/' + uid;
   }
   return this._httpRequest('GET',url,this._buildAuthHeader(),null).map((response)=>{
     if(response['body'] && uid === undefined){
       return <any>response['body'].map((transaction)=>{return new Transaction(transaction);});
     }else if(response['body']){
       return new Transaction(response.body);
     }
   });
 }
```

And then it's implementation in my BuddyService:

```
  constructor(private ApiService:ApiService,private cookie:CookieService) {
    this.checkCookie();
  }
  authenticate(username,password):void{
    this.ApiService.authenticate(username,password).subscribe((response)=>{
      if(!response['error']){
        this.ApiService.token = response.token;
        this.cookie.set('auth_token',this.ApiService.token);
        this.checkCookie();
      }else{
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }
  checkCookie():void{
    if(this.cookie.check('auth_token')){
      this.ApiService.token = this.cookie.get('auth_token');
      this.ApiService.verifyToken().subscribe((response)=>{
        if(!response['error']){
          this.init();
        }else{
          // console.log(response);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  init():void{
    this.ApiService.getTransaction(undefined).subscribe((data)=>{console.log(data);this.transactions = data;});
  }
```

When this is served and the page is loaded, everything functions as expected. Except that each call to the API is actually 2 calls, and OPTIONS request, followed by my real request causing in the example above this.transactions to always be undefined before it is ever filled. 
What am I doing wrong here? How can I subscribe to the result of the real request and not the OPTIONS request?

Thansk in advance!

EDIT:

```
 getTransaction(uid:number):Observable<Transaction[]>{
   let url = this.endPoint + '/transaction';
   if(uid !== undefined){
     url += '/' + uid;
   }
   let req = new HttpRequest(
     'GET',
     url,
     {
       headers:new HttpHeaders({'auth_token':this.token});
     }
   );
   return this.http.request(req).map((response)=>{
     console.log(response);
   });
 }
```

After slimming down to a more barebones version of my problem I am still seeing the same results. `console.log(response);` will first render `{type:0}` on the preflight and an `HttpResponse` on the true request.

I feel like this issue must effect everyone who makes cross-origin requests?

Answer (score 0):

The OPTIONS request is a preflight request for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: I undestand that, thank you. What I don't undestand is how why I am subscribed the the result of a preflight request. In AngularJs 1.x we also make a preflight request, but everytime I call it my promise does not return an empty response to the preflight and a full resopnse to the true request (my app is completely unaware that that the preflight ever took place unless there is an error). It just seems to me that if I have to account for the empty preflight result for each http request made it will require an extra layer of error checking in my app, which seems a step backwards from 1.x

Comment: That should not be happening. Never saw that before. Can you check if the method getTransaction() is called twice? Are you using Http or HttpClient?

Comment: HttpClient. getTransactions() is only being called the one time and when I check the network tab there are only two requests to that endpoint (The first being the preflight and the second being legitimate). Subscribe's anonymous callback is first receiving an 'undefined' 'data' from the preflight and then the expected data from the true request. As a workaround I have getTransaction checking the response for the existence of a body, if there is no body I return an error object and implement it like this:

Comment: `this.ApiService.getTransaction(undefined).subscribe((data)=>{!data['error'] ? this.transactions = data : this.transactions = [];});`

Comment: and what is this method  this._httpRequest ?

Comment: `_httpRequest(method,url,headers,params):Observable<any>{
   let req = new HttpRequest(
     method,
     url,
     {
       headers:headers
     }
   );
   return this.http.request(req);
 }`
An attempt to create a generic http method to allow me to GET,POST, and PUT all from the same method.
params are supposed to be optional POST or PUT data, but I'm realizing now that it's never used.

Comment: I don't think you will gain any benefit from that generic function as it is similar to the HttpClient and perhaps the reason of that weird response. Try using the HttpClient directly instead of _httpRequest and check if the response is correct.